# Join using LINQ between two tables, return records from only one of them

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join

Here's my code:

```
public IEnumerable<IUIUPCItemShort> GetActiveWithDefaultCost()
    {
        var query = from upc in DataManagerFactory.Get().Manage<IUPCItem>().GetAll()
                    join inv in DataManagerFactory.Get().Manage<IInventory>().GetAll() on upc.UPCID equals inv.UPCID
                    where inv.ExitDate == null
                         && upc.UnitCost == null
                    select upc;
        return
            query.Cast<IUIUPCItemShort>().ToList();
```

Basically, I'm trying to do a Join between two tables, `UPC` and `Inventory`, and would like to have a list of only `UPC` that satisfy the `WHERE` conditions since I only want to show the user a list of `UPC`. I obviously am doing something really wrong, because I get this message:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpressionN' to type 'SubSonic.Linq.Structure.ProjectionExpression'.

I assume the problem is in my Linq code, especifically in the `select upc;`
How can I do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is a query of `IUPCItem` items, not of `IUIUPCItemShort` items.  It would appear that they query provider doesn't know how to translate the `Cast` operation for that conversion.

If you know that `IUPCItem` in your C# code is convertible to a `IUIUPCItemShort` then iyou probably just want to avoid having the query provider try to process the `Cast`.  Ensure that it's done in Linq to Objects like so:

```
return query.AsEnumerable().
    Cast<IUIUPCItemShort>()
    .ToList();
```

If that doesn't work then it means the type really isn't implicitly convertible; you need to determine how to properly get an instance of `IUIUPCItemShort` from a `IUPCItem`, possibly creating a method to handle the conversion that you call using `Select`.

Comment: Adding AsEnumerable() did it. I figured it would be something as simple as that, but you saved me a few hours of research and trial and error. Thanks!